# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run this python script I got off the internet but keep getting this error why does it keep adding an extra \ in the path

Sorry I am a newbie to python

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\HOMEPC\\Downloads\\Image-Remover-Python-main\\saved_models\\u2net\\u2net.pth`

Here is the code

```
import os

currentDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

print("---Loading Model---")
model_name = 'u2net'
model_dir = os.path.join(currentDir, 'saved_models',
                         model_name, model_name + '.pth')
```

Comment: Windows natively uses backslashes. But also, a backslash is used to "escape" other special characters to remove their special meaning and use them as normal literals. This is useful for example for quotes (`'` and `"`) which could mess with string. This is also the case for the backslash itself. In order to prevent the backslash from escaping the following character, it needs to be escaped itself.

Comment: as white mentioned its the backslashed so you can use 
[os.path.normcase](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase) to normalize back to forward slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pathlib insteam of os.path

```
from pathlib import Path

currentDir = Path(__file__).parent

print("---Loading Model---")
model_name = 'u2net'
model_dir = currentDir / f'saved_models/{model_name}.pth'
```

I sugguest you change model_dir to model_file, because it is not a directory.

Besides, you should make sure this is a directory named saved_models in current path, which I think is why you code failed.